# How to force TTPhotoViewController reload image URL in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, three20

I feel good when I use Three20 framework to create a good iPhone application if you didn't try it before, just go [here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20) to try.

but the I want your help me to force TTPhotoViewController to reload the image after it initialized. At the moment, it seems load the exist image before and didn't active to viewDidLoad.

Could you help me? or give me any advice?

Answer (score 0):

A better place to ask this question is at the [Three20 Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/)

EDIT:
A good way to start is to put some breakpoints in the Three20 source code to see what, and how, code is being run.  I have found many undocumented (seriously, what ***is*** documented anyway?) hooks and callbacks.  If you don't see anything you can use, the best part of Three20 is that it is open source — you can edit the Three20 source to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I already asked in the Google Group. But I think it is better to post it here too. Stackoverflow.com has a lot of developer's attention.